# Links not sending on php script

Tags: php, chatscript

I have created a **chatting system** using PHP. When I run that script on *localhost* links are sent easily but when I run the same script on *VPS*, messages are sent and URLs are not sent, it does not show any type of error either. What is the reason?

Comment: _"What is the reason?"_ We can't possibly know that with the information you've provided. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What does "not sending" even mean?

Comment: @JamesZ I have created chatting system, While chatting with someone, texts, images, files are sent normally but when I try to send URLs then without showing any errors URLs are not sending.
I hope now my question is clear, 
I appreciate your response, Thank you

Comment: There's definitely no way of figuring this out without the code

Comment: Can you share some piece of code so that i can see what exactly  you are doing